# Getting a list of of outstanding merges with username and revision information from command line svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When merging in TortoiseSVN (e.g. from a release branch to trunk), there is a "Show Log" option to select your revisions to merge. This shows you all outstanding merges in black, and all completed merges are greyed out.

I basically want the same functionality from the command line in Windows: to be able to retrieve the list of all outstanding (eligible) merges from my release branch to trunk, including revision number, revision date, user name, revision message and possibly the files themselves.

I can use the issue the following command from my trunk folder to get a list of eligible (outstanding) revisions:

```
>svn mergeinfo http://svn.example.com/svn/myProject/branches/1.0 --show-revs eligible
r1001
r1002
r1006
```

but this literally only outputs a list of revision numbers.

I could manually key these revisions into the log command, and this gives me the information I want:

```
>svn log http://svn.example.com/svn/myProject/branches/1.0  -r 1006
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1006| rob| 2012-06-13 17:55:37 +0100 (Wed, 13 Jun 2012) | 1 line

Updated code documentation

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I effectively combine these two?

Answer (score 2):

I think --log will solve your issue,

svn mergeinfo http://svn.example.com/svn/myProject/branches/1.0 --show-revs eligible --log

If you want more info then try -v option.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution involving redirecting the output of the `svn mergeinfo` into a file, and using this to drive the `svn log` command:

```
svn mergeinfo http://svn.example.com/svn/myProject/branches/1.0--show-revs eligible > revs.txt
FOR /F %k in (revs.txt) DO svn log http://svn.example.com/svn/myProject/branches/1.0 -r %k -v
DEL revs.txt
```

This does what I want - but I'm sure I've seen it done directly via the svn command line before.